# use in-memory sqlite in QT

Tags: qt, sqlite, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

I created a QSqlQuery to get some value from an in-memory database, which been set by

> setDatabaseName(":memory:")

When I execute the query, it gives me a QSqlError

> QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")

However, when I change the database to be a file database by simply just set name to be "test.sqlite" for example, the query works perfectly without any changes.

Does anyone have any idea why this situation happened?  Are there are any difference I need to know to set the query for in-memory database?

Comment: Are you creating the tables when using the in-memory database?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I do create the tables. Every operation works fine in C++ class, it just cannot be used in qml.

Comment: Please provide a minimal and complete example of a `.qml` file that reproduces the issue. Since you say that every operation fails, you only need to show one operation. You're probably doing something wrong, but how can we knwo?